# how to use Adiantum for encryption in android?

Tags: android, encryption

Recently Google has launched [Adiantum](https://opensource.google.com/projects/adiantum) for efficient encryption . I've been using AES for that , but as google stated

> Most new Android devices have hardware support for AES via the ARMv8
>   Cryptography Extensions. However, Android runs on a wide range of
>   devices.  In order to offer low cost options, device manufacturers
>   sometimes use low-end processors such as the ARM Cortex-A7, which does
>   not have hardware support for AES. On these devices, AES is so slow
>   that it would result in a poor user experience; apps would take much
>   longer to launch, and the device would generally feel much slower

So ,Considering this case .I wanna go for Adiantum for encryption which uses basically [ChaCha family](https://cr.yp.to/chacha.html) with [Poly1305 authenticator](https://cr.yp.to/mac.html). My Question is .

1. Can we use this encryption in Android while developing ? or its just for Android OS ?
2. I couldn't find any documents related to how to implement it.

Would be great If you guys can shed some light on. It would be helpful to all if more information available on it.